# Is there a Wine-like application for wrapping Mac applications?

Tags: windows, macos, emulator

The application [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) allows you to run windows applications natively on several OS's. Is there a similar application that allows you to run Mac applications on a Windows machine without a VM?

Answer (score 1):

[Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/) probably close to it. As mentioned on site:

> Wine lets you run Windows software on Linux, and Darling does the same for macOS software.
> Darling is a translation layer that lets you run macOS software on Linux.
> Darling runs macOS software directly without using a hardware emulator.

> **Does it support GUI apps?**
> Almost! This took us a lot of time and effort, but we finally have basic experimental support for running simple graphical applications.

Darling can be [used in Windows with WSL2](https://docs.darlinghq.org/wsl-build.html):

> Darling should work with no problems on WSL2, as this is essentially a standard virtual machine with a full Linux kernel. WSL1 is more complicated and is not currently working.
> As Darling no longer uses a Linux Kernel Module, no special instructions are needed for either WSL1 or WSL2. Use the standard [Linux build instructions](https://docs.darlinghq.org/build-instructions.html).